# Doc comments missing from imported typed functions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, tsdoc

I've ran into a problem when creating some react hooks. The hooks had their types and doc comments defined like this:

```js
type UseA = () => {
  fnA: () => void;
  ...
}

/** Some hook */
export const useA: UseA = () => {
  ...
}
```

When I imported these hooks into my components the UseA type and the doc comments were missing. Instead VS Code just inferred the return types of the hooks.

```js
import { useA } from './useA';
// here VSCode shows the original type definition and doc comments

...

const { fnA } = useA();
// here useA's type is just () => { fnA: () => void; ... } instead of UseA
// doc comments are also missing from the hook
```

After changing the hook's type so that only the return type is defined

```js
type UseA = { fnA: () => void; ... };
const useA = (): UseA => { ... };
```

VS can now see the doc comments on `useA()` and it has the correct `() => UseA` type. My question is, why wasn't it working with the first type definition? Is this the intentional behavior? VS could see the type and docs in the import statement so why were they missing in the component? Maybe it has something to do with tsconfig?

Comment: Seems like you've posted a hint on the code that you have. That's a bit confusing. Could you post the actual code that you actually have?

Comment: Sometimes JSDocs are lost as a result of the destructuring assignment. Unlikely, but might be the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The actual code is way longer and this example produces the same result for the purpose of the question. The `/** Some hook */` comment and the original type are lost when importing and using the hook. `fnA` actually keeps it's doc comments after destructuring.